# Optimum number of texture atlas images

Tags: libgdx, scene2d

I have managed to squeze all my sprites in a single textureatlas png file of size 1024x1024. The trouble is that it would have been nice to integrate some sprites that are bigger in size and would have made the game appear more hd like on tablets and phones with bigger resolution, but that would make the atlas hold 2 images instead of one. Is that a performance issue on some phones? What`s the ideal size and ideal number of pngs an atlas should hold so as not to hold up frames unnecessary?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "ideal" size of an atlas is the amount of memory it takes at runtime and what size is supported by on your platform's GPU.  Conventional wisdom is that 1024x1024 is definitely safe.  2048x2048 is probably fine (especially on newer phones), but larger than that might not be supported on some devices.

The number of textures stored in the atlas isn't a problem (the more the merrier --- the goal is to load the texture into the GPU and keep it there as long as possible, so the more stuff that uses it the better).  So, it is fine if there are unused textures on the atlas image.  If you can fit all the variations of HD/regular sprites onto one reasonably sized atlas image, then go for it.

If you have some sprites that have "HD" and "regular" versions, and some sprites that are used in "both" resolutions, it may be worthwhile to create an "HD" atlas that contains the "HD" and "both" sprites, and a "regular" atlas that contains the "regular" and "both" sprites.  Your game would ship with both atlases, but only use one at runtime.

All that said, I think you'd be fine with two 1MB atlas images.